# How to call mysql function using querydsl?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I am in little hurry so, i just want to ask a quick question about querydsl. According to my research, query dsl doesn't support stored procedure but can support database functions. My Question is how can we invoke those database functions using querydsl?

Comment: Wouldn't [this article](http://luisfpg.blogspot.be/2013/02/the-beauty-of-querydsl-in-sorting.html) answer your question ?

Comment: yeah, i have gone through it lots of time. But it is little out dated based on the current version of querydsl.

Comment: My bad. Consider I haven't said anything then :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use TemplateExpression based injections of arbitrary JPQL syntax into your query.

e.g.

```
query.where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("func1({0}, {1})", arg1, arg2));
```

If you use Hibernate 4.3 or any other JPA 2.1 compliant provider you can use the FUNCTION syntax to invoke SQL functions https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350843

So the example would turn into

```
query.where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("function('func1', {0}, {1})", arg1, arg2)"));
```

Comment: Wow.. what a coincidence timo.. i just saw and read slide.. you got it almost all in it i need to know.. thank you.. and i ll definitely try your suggestion..

Comment: @Timo I'm trying this but i receive an: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node

Comment: Nice one. And also is it possible to handle more functions (nested inner functions) in a single call?

Comment: so ... basically ... QueryDSL doesnt support typesafe functions although it would be possible to extract the types via @NamedStoredProcedureQuery. Thats sad.

Comment: Hi, @renanleandrof, have you solve the problem? I got the same error: `unexpected AST node`. My code: `Expressions.booleanTemplate("FIND_IN_SET({0}, {1})", arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @elva Yes. The problem was with the versions of querydsl in my project. Make sure you have the last one.

Answer (score 0):

example of call mysql function **find_in_set**:

```
query.where(Expressions.booleanTemplate("find_in_set({0}, {1}) > 0", 1, "1,2,3"));
```

'> 0' Is a must, else thorw unexpected AST node