# QueryDSL: How to order by NEWID()?

Tags: sql-server, querydsl

How can I write:

```
SELECT TOP 1 x
FROM y
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

using [querydsl-sql](http://www.querydsl.com/)?

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4980733/14731 for an explanation of what the query does)

Comment: So the querydsl is something line Linq for Java?

Comment: @alas querydsl's scope is limited to building type-safe SQL statements. I've never used LINQ but I believe it has a much wider scope.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to support specific sql server proprietary functions like newid(). So, basically you are looking for the querydsl-sql query to return a random record from a table, right?

Comment: @alas More precisely, I am looking for a way to invoke custom functions from within QueryDSL.

Comment: so wouldn't TemplateExpression apply? see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984343/how-to-call-mysql-function-using-querydsl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
import com.mysema.query.types.expr.StringExpression;
import com.mysema.query.types.template.StringTemplate;

/**
 * SQL Server specific expressions.
 *
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class CustomExpressions {

    private static final StringExpression newId = StringTemplate.create("NEWID()");

    /**
     * Prevent construction.
     */
    private CustomExpressions() {
    }

    /**
     * @return NEWID()
     */
    public static StringExpression newId() {
        return newId;
    }
}

[...]

CustomExpressions expressions = new CustomExpressions();
new SQLQuery(connection, configuration).query().from(y).
  orderBy(expressions.newId().asc()).
  limit(1).uniqueResult(x);
```

Comment: +1 for the `StringTemplate` use, it's a superior solution to the one I offered. Personally I would favour a utility class for `CustomExpressions` - final, with a private constructor and a `public static StringExpression newId()` method. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @RobertBain, for the current implementation of this class, I agree. For a singleton with mutable state, I tend to leave the class as-is and use IoC to instantiate it as a singleton. Anyway, I'll update the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This looks fine, but the empty constructor should be private.

Comment: If I were to be super-pedantic, `newId` should be `NEW_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant solution but you could use the `addFlag(QueryFlag.Position position, String flag)` method, documented [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/ProjectableSQLQuery.html#addFlag(com.mysema.query.QueryFlag.Position,%20java.lang.String)).

E.G.

```
query.addFlag(QueryFlag.Position.END, "ORDER BY NEWID()");
```

I find when queryDSL refuses to play nice, and by "play nice" I mean when the API doesn't support what I'm trying to do, there are a few ways to essentially force a `String` into your query. This is the least bad way, in my experience.