# How to use querydsl SQLExpressions with Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I'm trying to apply a `mysql` specific function to a querydsl definition:

```
entity.departureDate.after(SQLExpressions.addDays(entity.departureDate, 10))
```

Results in generated sql:

```
select * from mytable where departureDate > add_days(departureDate,?1)
```

But that results in an exception, as `add_days` is not a known mysql function:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION mytable.add_days does not exist
```

Question: how can I tell `querydsl` to use `DATE_ADD()` function instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works, but still feels kind of ugly. Please comment if there are better solutions than:

```
entity.departureDate.after(
        Expressions.dateTemplate(LocalDate.class,
                                 "FUNCTION('ADDDATE', {0}, {1})",
                                 entity.departureDate,
                                 10)));
```

This solution can also be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22988168/1194415